# How to image resize in this code

Tags: php, yii2

```
Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] = Yii::$app->basePath . '/uploads/';
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'photo');
    $model->filename = $image->name;
    $ext = end((explode(".", $image->name)));
    $model->photo = Security::generateRandomKey().".{$ext}"; 
    $path = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] . $model->photo;
    if($model->save()){
        $image->saveAs($path);
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
} else {
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I want to image resize code.
So which code added in this code?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code:
// add this method on your controller and then use resize 
function resize($imagePath, $destinationWidth, $destinationHeight, $destinationPath)
    {
        if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
            $imageInfo = getimagesize($imagePath);
            $sourceWidth = $imageInfo[0];
            $sourceHeight = $imageInfo[1];
            $source_aspect_ratio = $sourceWidth / $sourceHeight;
            $thumbnail_aspect_ratio = $destinationWidth / $destinationHeight;
            if ($sourceWidth <= $destinationWidth && $sourceHeight <= $destinationHeight) {
                $thumbnail_image_width = $sourceWidth;
                $thumbnail_image_height = $sourceHeight;
            } elseif ($thumbnail_aspect_ratio > $source_aspect_ratio) {
                $thumbnail_image_width = (int) ($destinationHeight * $source_aspect_ratio);
                $thumbnail_image_height = $destinationHeight;
            } else {
                $thumbnail_image_width = $destinationWidth;
                $thumbnail_image_height = (int) ($destinationWidth / $source_aspect_ratio);
            }
            $destinationWidth = $thumbnail_image_width;
            $destinationHeight = $thumbnail_image_height;
            $mimeType = $imageInfo['mime'];
            $destinationWidth = $thumbnail_image_width;
            $destinationHeight = $thumbnail_image_height;
            $destination = imagecreatetruecolor($destinationWidth, $destinationHeight);
            if ($mimeType == 'image/jpeg' || $mimeType == 'image/pjpeg') {
                $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagePath);
                imagecopyresampled($destination, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $destinationWidth, $destinationHeight, $sourceWidth, $sourceHeight);
                $destinationPath = $destinationPath;
                imagejpeg($destination, $destinationPath);
            } else if ($mimeType == 'image/gif') {
                $source = imagecreatefromgif($imagePath);
                imagecopyresampled($destination, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $destinationWidth, $destinationHeight, $sourceWidth, $sourceHeight);
                $destinationPath = $destinationPath;
                imagegif($destination, $destinationPath);
            } else if ($mimeType == 'image/png' || $mimeType == 'image/x-png') {
                $source = imagecreatefrompng($imagePath);
                imagecopyresampled($destination, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $destinationWidth, $destinationHeight, $sourceWidth, $sourceHeight);
                $destinationPath = $destinationPath;
                imagepng($destination, $destinationPath);
            } else {
                echo 'This image type is not supported.';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'The requested file does not exist.';
        }
    }
    // ==========================================================
    $destinationPath = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'] ."resize/". $model->photo;//note: create new directory (resize) in uploads directory
        $this->resize($path, $destinationWidth=100, $destinationHeight=100, $destinationPath);
```